# How to voice type in LibreOffice?

Tags: 22.04, libreoffice, speech-recognition

LibreOffice does not seem to have an inbuilt voice type feature. Is there any way to enable voice typing in LibreOffice?

If not, is there any other *free and open source* software with which I can voice type in LibreOffice?

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: Actually, I don't think LibreOffice is relevant, either.  I think some intermediate software, separate from LibreOffice, is needed which converts voice commands into keystrokes...  And no, I don't know of the software for Ubuntu.  (And I would disagree with your comment that the version of Ubuntu is not relevant -- it is because you would need a piece of software that's available in 20.04.)

Comment: @Ray OK, I will delete my comment and update the question.

Comment: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/13303/can-i-speak-text-and-have-libreoffice-type-it/ :)

Comment: @Rinzwind That question is 8 years old, and its answer may not be valid. Even if LibreOffice itself does not have the capability, there may be another FOSS software which can convert from speech to text and input it in LibreOffice. Dragon seems to be a proprietary software.

Comment: Have you checked googles offerings? I think Chrome has such an offering but I have not tried it. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/4492226?hl=en#zippy=%2Ctype-with-your-voice

Comment: @C.S.Cameron Thanks. I found some some websites which convert voice to text and put it into a textbox in the web browser. But I am looking for a native application which would put the text in LibreOffice Writer.

Answer (score 0):

For simply dictation, you might like [nerd-dictation](https://github.com/ideasman42/nerd-dictation). For a full-on keyboard alternative, there's [Numen](https://numenvoice.com), which let's you command keys/actions as well as dictate.

They're both FOSS and use the [Vosk speech recognition toolkit](https://alphacephei.com/vosk).

Comment: "With numen you mainly say words that map to keys." Is that what the OP is looking for?

Comment: Great! From the link, I could not tell that it could take dictation. Thanks for the edit. +1